# What is the difference between 神河and 河神

Tags: difference

河神 to 神河  difference

神河文明

Tientsin Mystic (河神)

Is there any difference in the use 河神 to 神河?

Comment: 河神 = river god; 神河 = divine river

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words are different in "**central word**(中心语)".

According to structure of phrase, they're both "偏正短语". It means, it has a "central word"(usually a noun)("正" of "偏正") and a word to describe it(定语)("偏" of "偏正"). **The central word is the most important part of a phrase. It is the essence of the thing the word means.**

In "河神", the central word is "神". "河" is a word to describe "神".

```
Where's the god? (神 is the central word)
In the river. (河 is the 定语 to describe the living place of 神)
```

In "神河", "河" is the central word, and "神" is the 定语.

```
神河属于河神.
shorten it: 河属于神.
```

Answer (score 0):

'Tientsin Mystic' in Chinese is 天神奧秘 (Tien Tsin is a transliteration), I don't know why it is translated as 河神 by you

- 河神 = River god
- 神河 = Divine river (not a commonly used term in Chinese)

> [神河文明](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%A5%9E%E6%B2%B3%E6%96%87%E6%98%8E)

> 神河文明，动画《超神学院》和《雄兵连》系列中的文明。
> 神河文明属于超神宇宙下以知宇宙文明最高阶层的文明之一，已经毁灭。

神河文明 is a fictional term from a Japanese anime. It literally  means 'Divine River Civilization' or 'God River Civilization'